# I am trying to access navigation drawer so that when i click on the top left corner of app bar, I can access settings in a new activity

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, android-navigationview

I am trying to access navigation drawer so that when i click on the top left corner of app bar, I can access settings in a new activity. Right now what I get when I click on the upper left corner and then click settings is the menu retracts and nothing else happens. I have a bottom navigation bar also. Please help. Here's what I have so far:

NavigationActivity.java

```
package com.tt.lateoclock;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.tt.lateoclock.Prevalent.Prevalent;
import com.tt.lateoclock.ui.findFood.FindFoodFragment;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    DrawerLayout drawer;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Menu menu;

    private DatabaseReference merchantRef;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    Intent settingsIntent;
    NavController navController;
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);


        //merchantRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Merchants");


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setTitle("Home");


        drawer = findViewById(R.id.container);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.bot_nav_view);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_find_food, R.id.navigation_favorites, R.id.navigation_map, R.id.navigation_receipts, R.id.navigation_settings)
                .build();
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView name = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        CircleImageView user_image = (CircleImageView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_image);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id=menuItem.getItemId();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //it's possible to do more actions on several items, if there is a large amount of items I prefer switch(){case} instead of if()
                if (id==R.id.navigation_settings){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                //This is for maintaining the behavior of the Navigation view
                NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem, navController);
                //This is for closing the drawer after acting on it
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });


        name.setText(Prevalent.currentUser.getName());
        
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController=Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_settings:
                settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(settingsIntent);


            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_find_food:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new FindFoodFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_favorites:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new com.tt.lateoclock.ui.favorites.FavoritesFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_receipts:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new com.tt.lateoclock.ui.receipts.ReceiptsFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_settings:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(settingsIntent);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NavigationActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            />
        
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bot_nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="196dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" >
        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

bottom_nav_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_find_food"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_dining_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_find_food" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_favorites"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_favorites" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_map"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_map_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_map" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_receipts"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_receipt_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_receipts" />

</menu>
```

drawer_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_message"
            android:title="Message"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_message"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:title="Profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
            android:title="Settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:enabled="true"/>
</menu>
```

mobile_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_find_food">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_find_food"
        android:name="com.tt.lateoclock.ui.findFood.FindFoodFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_find_food"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_find_food" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_favorites"
        android:name="com.tt.lateoclock.ui.favorites.FavoritesFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_favorites"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_favorites" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_map"
        android:name="com.tt.lateoclock.ui.map.MapFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_map"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_receipts"
        android:name="com.tt.lateoclock.ui.receipts.ReceiptsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_receipts"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_receipts" />

</navigation>
```

Comment: can you provide the navigation_graph xml file?

Comment: The navigation_graph.xml file is at the bottom of drawer_menu.xml as mobile_navigation.xml. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `activity_navigation.xml` to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    ...>

    <RelativeLayout...>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_gravity="start"
         .../>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also you have to handle the click on the settings item with `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

About the `DrawerLayout` [check the doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer):

> Note: When using NavigationUI, the top app bar helpers automatically transition between the drawer icon and the Up icon as the current destination changes. You **don't need** to use `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

In your code remove the code about the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and use:

```
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
        new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(...........)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
            .build();
```

Comment: Wow, this worked, but now the navigation drawer comes open and refuses to close. The bottom navigation works as well. What do I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here your Setting activity is not a part of the `NavigationGraph` (i.e. not a fragment it's a separate activity).

And when you hit the drawer burger and choose the Setting, it won't go to the Setting as you didn't launch the intent on the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` of the `NavigationView`

To fix that:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        int id=menuItem.getItemId();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //it's possible to do more actions on several items, if there is a large amount of items I prefer switch(){case} instead of if()
        if (id==R.id.navigation_settings){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(NavigationActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class); // <<< Here is the change
            startActivity(settingsIntent); // <<< Here is the change
        }
        //This is for maintaining the behavior of the Navigation view
        NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem, navController);
        //This is for closing the drawer after acting on it
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
});
```

## Update

Replace

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

With

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: I did the changes you recommended. It does not open a new activity when i press settings. It just closes the menu when I press settings.

Comment: @ReinaldoGift does the toast "Settings" Shown to you when you hit the Setting from the drawer?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: It says it cant resolve the method. navView is for the bottom navigation view, while navigationView is for the navigation view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `<activity>` destination to your navigation graph for starting another activity:

```
<activity
    android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
    android:name="com.your.package.SettingsActivity" />
```

Then, the default behavior of `setupWithNavController()` / `onNavDestinationSelected()` will start your activity for you. You wouldn't need to write any custom code or manual calls to `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` to get this behavior.

You should also strongly consider adding `menuCategory="secondary"` to your `navigation_settings` menu item as per the [`onNavDestinationSelected()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)) to avoid your current destination from being popped off the back stack.

Answer (score 0):

Add the OnClick method in the menu item

```
<item
     android:id="@+id/nav_whats_app"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings"
     android:title="@string/menu_settings"
     android:onClick="onOpenSettings" />
```

Then add the method in the activity like this

```
//Kotlin Android
fun onOpenSettings(item: MenuItem) {
//... open settings here
}
```

Java Code

```
//Java Android
void onOpenSettings(MenuItem item) {
//... open settings here
}
```

To close any Navigation drawer, just call

```
val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    }
```